# setInterval in chartjs

Tags: settimeout, setinterval

Good morning,
I use chartjs to display multiple charts on the same page and it works great.

However, my graphics are not updating and I have this error that I cannot resolve.

```
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 99ms
```

Here is my code

```
var getData = function() {
        $.getJSON("page.php", function (result) {
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                var count_length = result.length;
                if (chart_88146186.data.labels.length < count_length) {
                    shift_data(chart_88146186);
                    addData(chart_88146186, field.navigateur, field.count_navigateur);
                } else {
                    addNewData(chart_88146186, count_length-1, field.count_navigateur, field.navigateur);
                }
            });

        });
    }
    setTimeout(getData, 2000);
    setInterval(getData, 10000);
```

I think I have too many graphics on the page, that's why it's blocking